# jdk 1.7 and ubuntu 32 bit compatibility

Tags: java

I want to run a video in JFrame in which I have used Vlcj and JMF framework and I have successfully achieved my task in Windows. But when I tried to do the same work in Linux (32 bit) it gives me fatal error.

I did discovery on the google and people are saying that there is issue with Linux 32 bit and Jdk 1.7.

Is it true ?

Response appreciated.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about specific problems with Linux 32bit and Java 1.7 JDK. But by default most distributions ship with OpenJDK Java. I would try installing and switching the Oracle JDK it might help.

You can find a good Ubuntu how to for that here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-installing-oracle-java7-on-ubuntu-linux/